# Edge length of hyperbolic tesselations

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

If I have a general uniform tesselation in hyperbolic plane (same configuration of regular polygons at every vertex, but multiple types of polygons allowed), how can I find the edge length and/or inner angles of the polygons so they'd fit?

For example: a truncated {3,7} tesselation has two hexagon and one heptagon at every vertex. What is its edge length and what are the inner angles of the two types of polygons?

Comment: is just a lot of calculation, first calculate the angles of the isocleses triangles that make up the polygon(s)   and then by AAA calculate the sides of the triangle / polygon

Comment: link on wikipedia: Truncated order-7 triangular tiling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_order-7_triangular_tiling

Comment: Well, the wikipedia link doesn't really mention lengths or angles. The hyperbolic applet by Don Hatch (http://www.plunk.org/~hatch/HyperbolicApplet/) only computes the edge length by iteration, so I guess there's no exact algorithm available?

Comment: Actually the edge length for this tiling can be computed analytically.  It's a bit messy, but ultimately the result matches the edge length calculated numerically in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the right triangle with corner angles

$$ \alpha=\frac\pi7,\quad\beta=\frac\pi3,\quad\gamma=\frac\pi2 $$

It is a building block for a tiling with regular heptagons, three meeting at each vertex.

The [hyperbolic law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines) gives you

\begin{align*}
\cosh a &= \frac{\cos\alpha + \cos\beta\cos\gamma}{\sin\beta\sin\gamma}
= \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\beta} \\
\cosh b &= \frac{\cos\beta + \cos\gamma\cos\alpha}{\sin\gamma\sin\alpha}
= \frac{\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha} \\
\cosh c &= \frac{\cos\gamma + \cos\alpha\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}
= \frac{\cos\alpha\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta} = \cot\alpha\cot\beta
\end{align*}

Now you compare this to the truncated heptagon. That's again a regular heptagon, so $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ stay the same, but you get a different $\beta'$, resulting in different lengths $a',b',c'$. The truncated heptagon is rotated inside the original one, so that its corners line up with the edge midpoints of the original. (I forgot this point in my first version of this answer.)

[image: Illustration]

The distance between inner corner and outer edge is $b-c'$. If you want regular hexagons, then you have to make this equal to the length $a'$ of the shorter leg, since both of these are exactly half a hexagon edge. So you want to find a $\beta'$ such that

$$
b-c'=
\operatorname{arcosh}\frac{\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha}-\operatorname{arcosh}(\cot\alpha\cot\beta') = \operatorname{arcosh}\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\beta'}
= a'
$$

I know of no closed formula to solve this kind of equation. I guess its transcendental, but I'm no expert there. You can solve this numerically, and will find something like

$$\beta'\approx1.0941107896648635317725955439550573051099051847044121941115690465$$

So instead of the $128.57°$ of a Euclidean heptagon or the $120°$ of the 7,3 tiling you get heptagons with interior angle $2\beta'\approx125.38°$. The interior angle of the hexagon is $180°-\beta'\approx117.31$ which of course compares to $120°$ in a Euclidean hexagon.

Using the $\beta'$ from above, you can find that the edge length of both the hexagons and the heptagons is

$$2a'\approx0.3343951728664474230865747047250440499075073624066706216059350025$$

The circumradius of the heptagon is

$$c'\approx0.3780772453203193756871600978881466991323285422408574087213795657$$

Comment: In the end, I looked through a source code of tilings applet and copied the iterative algorithm found there. Your results confirm my, which means I did it correctly. May I ask if there's a simple relation between edge length of a regular n-gon and its circumradius? I guess the hyperbolic law of cosines works here as well, just wondering if it needs iterative algorithm as well or not.

Comment: @Marek14: When you know the $n$ of an $n$-gon, you know $\alpha=\frac\pi n$. When you know the edge length, you know $2a$. Since $\gamma$ is always a right angle in this subdivision, you can compute the circumradius $c$ using the hyperbolic law of sines: $$\sinh c\sin\alpha=\sinh a$$ You'd need the cosine law for the incircle radius $b$, but that's not what you were asking about.

Comment: sorry late remark : you also have $ b' = c - a $ and after that $a'$ and $ c'$ can be calculated, no iteration needed :)

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ at a vertex of a regular hyperbolic $n$-gon with side length $s$ is given by

$$\sin\tfrac12\theta=\frac{\cos\tfrac12\tfrac{2\pi}n}{\cosh\tfrac12s}.$$

This is monotonically decreasing in $s$. As the polygon shrinks we have $\lim_{s\to0}\sin\tfrac12\theta=\cos\tfrac12\tfrac{2\pi}n$, or $\lim_{s\to0}\theta=\pi-\frac{2\pi}n$, the Euclidean $n$-gon angle. As the polygon grows we have $\lim_{s\to\infty}\theta=0$.

If your hyperbolic tiling has a vertex type $(n_1.n_2.n_3.\cdots)$, for the polygons to fit exactly around the vertex we need

$$2\pi=\sum_k\theta_k=\sum_k2\arcsin\frac{\cos\tfrac12\tfrac{2\pi}{n_k}}{\cosh\tfrac12s}.$$

This sum is also monotonically decreasing, so there is at most one solution $s$. There is a solution if and only if the sum in the Euclidean case $s\to0$ is greater than $2\pi$ (using the Intermediate Value Theorem). I don't think we can find the solution in closed form, in general.

Multiplying that equation by $\tfrac12i$ and exponentiating gives us this product of unit complex numbers:

$$-1=\prod_ke^{i\theta_k/2}=\prod_k\left(\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\cos\tfrac12\tfrac{2\pi}{n_k}}{\cosh\tfrac12s}\right)^2}+i\frac{\cos\tfrac12\tfrac{2\pi}{n_k}}{\cosh\tfrac12s}\right);$$

since $\cos\tfrac\pi n$ is always an algebraic number, this shows that $\cosh\tfrac12s$ is also an algebraic number.

Comment: The first formula, for $\sin\tfrac12\theta$, can be derived from the polar law of cosines $$\cos\gamma=-\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cosh c$$ applied to the small triangle shown in MvG's answer.

Comment: Another approach: Draw a circle centred on the vertex with radius $\tfrac12s$, and perpendicular bisectors to the edges; the bisectors pass through the centres of the polygons and are tangent to the circle, and form the edges of a new polygon. So your problem is equivalent to that of finding the inradius ($\tfrac12s$) of a polygon with given angles ($\tfrac{2\pi}{n_k}$).