# Does any hyperbolic tiling pattern exists which can be scale smoothly

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

I know that some (maybe all) tilings patterns on Euclidean plane can be scale up or down at any ratio. For example, the edge length of a square grid can be scale from 2 to 0.5 smoothly, and meanwhile the square tiling pattern still can be hold.

[image: Square grid] [image: heptagonal tiling]

Based on this geometric intuition and the fact that hyperbolic plane is also a homogeneous space. I had thought that hyperbolic tiling patterns can be scale smoothly. But now I am developing a drawing tool to draw hyperbolic tiling patterns on Poincare disk, and I meet some difficulties on this assumption, I was failed to draw a pattern with the length of edge 1.

Thanks for comments from @IvanNeretin , we know that the above geometric intuition on Euclidean plane may not generally hold on hyperbolic plane: for a given negative constant curvature $c$ and a specific tiling pattern, at least we can solve the proper edge length $l$ numerically. ref [Edge length of hyperbolic tesselations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331199/edge-length-of-hyperbolic-tesselations)

So my question is

- Does any hyperbolic tiling pattern exists which can be scale smoothly? or a kind of global rigidity hold for all hyperbolic tiling patterns?

Images are from related Wikipedia articles.

Comment: There's no scaling here. You need your tile with certain angles, and as you scale it, the angles change.

Comment: Thanks, @IvanNeretin. If scaling is not correct as you mentioned, does it means the length of edge are only range from some specific values?

Comment: Values? _One_ value, I'd say, once you've fixed the tiling type.

Comment: OK, that means it is a global phenomenon and a kind of rigidity. And how could we calculate this one proper length?

Comment: Rigidity, yes, that's the right word. As for the calculation details, here I'm stepping outside of my expertise. There are many questions to that effect here on MSE, though. Here's one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331199/edge-length-of-hyperbolic-tesselations. Also, there is a game named "HyperRogue"...

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Yeah, there is no scaling in non-Euclidean geometry. You could do things like the e.g., the Goldberg-Coxeter construction, which works by adding small hexagons in a regular way. (See http://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper/geoms.php or in HyperRogue: experiment in geometry -> variations -> change x and y)

Comment: There is also the binary tiling, in which you can have as narrow tiles as you want -- for the "binary" tiling the height is fixed, but with a smaller growth ratio the height will be smaller too.

Comment: Thanks @ZenoRogue , I will have a try for HyperRogue

Answer (score 0):

In the question, the scale operation in hyperbolic space is not defined very clearly. So we may clarify it first. As any Euclidean scale operation, a scale operation in hyperbolic are also:

- An one-parameter transformation group with a radius parameter $r$ ($r$ may not related with length)
- these transformations have a special originate point as a shared fix point when radius parameter changes

Under this definition, I constructed several patterns which can be scaled up or down.

The first one is with a construction factor 2

[image: a scalable grid with factor of 2]

The second one is with a construction factor 3

[image: a scalable grid with factor of 3]

We may construct a pattern like this with any integer factors.

Comment: Generally when we talk about a 'tiling' of a space though, we mean finite regions and when we talk about tessellations particularly we usually speak of a finite number of 'shapes'. Every tile in this tiling is infinite and every one of them is distinct.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Steven. Do you mean this construction is not a proper answer to the question?

Comment: Basically so — it's a legitimate scaling-invariant partition of the hyperbolic plane, and that's a fine thing in its own right, but I (personally) wouldn't consider it as a tiling pattern. It's analagous (literally, directly) to partitioning $\mathbb{R}^2$ into concentric circles of geometrically scaling radius.

Comment: Thanks for your clarify, then I will not accept this answer :-)

Comment: You still do not have a proper definition of a "smooth scaling." What do you mean by a "radius parameter"? In what sense do elements of your group "scale"?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry for late reply, since too busy. the original ideal point (0,0) is the fix point as mentioned above, we can scale up or down very intuitively, but I need verify whether it is smooth.

Comment: And @StevenStadnicki if I remove tiling from the title, the question and answer are valid?  I will ask another question to reflect the scaling-invariant part?