# Which pairs of hyperbolic tessellations share edge length?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

For any set of regular polygons, it's possible to find edge length that allows to fit these polygons around a vertex in either spherical, Euclidean (for edge $0$), or hyperbolic plane. If we disregard the Euclidean case, how can I find sets that share the same edge length?

I know of two such pairs: $(3,10,3,10)$ and $(4,5,4,5)$, and $(4,10,4,10)$ and $(5,6,5,6)$. In both cases, two polygons add up to straight angle, so a vertex containing those four types of polygons shares the same edge length, which allows for various hybrid tilings.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: I expect you can write this as a Diophantine equation, with additional restriction that the integer variables be positive. That would catch peoples interest

Comment: Why don't you just ask how to calculate the edge length of a single tiling? Also, whenever you have a problem in hyperbolic geometry, try to translate it to an equivalent problem in spherical geometry, which is easier for some people to visualize and thus to solve.

Comment: The first such pair of tilings that comes to my mind is $\{8,4\}$ and $\{3,8\}$; take the octagonal tiling, and you can break each octagon into $8$ regular triangles by putting a vertex at its centre.

Comment: True, @mr_e_man, there's an infinite family of {3,2n} and {2n,n}.The thing is that closed form for an edge length of an arbitrary tiling with multiple kinds of polygons is by itself complicated.

Comment: I see you already did ask for the [edge length of a tiling](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331199/472818), but the answer given is not general. I think the $\cosh$ of the edge length must be an algebraic number.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I have researched this question further and found some more examples.
There are, apparently, three infinite families:
1. A triangular tiling {3,n} shares edge with {n,n/2} (because one n-gon can be built from n triangles). Even for odd n, this allows additional vertices (for example {3,7}, (3^5,7), (3^3,7^2) and (3,7^3) all have the same edge).
2. A vertex of form (4,n,2n) and a vertex of form (3,4^2,n) share an edge.
3. A vertex of form (3,3n)^5n. Every combination of 4 triangles and 1 3n-gon can be replaced by 3 5n-gons while keeping the same edge length.

Comment: Other identities: (3,4,8,40) and (3,5,8^2); (3,5,6,18) and (3,6^2,9); (3,4,10,20), (3^4,4^2), (3^2,4,5^2), and {5,4}; (3,5,12^2) and (4,5^2,12); (4,4,10,30) and {4,5}; (3^2,4^2,6^2), (3,4,6,18^2), and {18,4}; (3^3,5,20^2), (3^2,4,5^2,20), and (3,4^2,5^3); {3,10}/{5,6}/{10,5} and various mixings thereof; (3^3,4,7^3), (3^2,4^3,7^2), (3,4^5,7), and {4,7}; {8,6} and {4,8}; {30,6} and (5^5,30^2); (3,4)^6 and (3^5,4,24^4); (4,12)^5, (5,6)^5, and four mixed vertices from gradual replacement of (4,12) with (5,6); (3,9)^6 and (3^7,4^6,9); and a few others.