# How can we find sizes in a uniform tiling of the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tiling, gyrovectors

Given a certain [uniform tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane) of the [hyperbolic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) (for example, one given by its [vertex configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_configuration), if that specifies a tiling unambiguously, or a tiling specified by some other means, whatever that means is?), how can we find

1. The length of a side in the tiling, and
2. The distance from the center of a polygon to the middle of the side of the same polygon, for each polygon type?

For simplicity, we can assume the curvature $\kappa$ of the plane to be $-1$ (or equivalently, the radius $R$, which is [defined](https://andbloch.github.io/K-Stereographic-Model/) as $R = \sqrt{-\kappa}$ by some sources, to be $1$).

Note that the the number of sides of each tile and the valence of each vertex is given by the vertex configuration, and that all sides in a uniform tiling have the same length.

I have made the following attempt to calculate 2. for the special case of the tiling [$\{p,q\}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol) (in the picture I have chosen $p=4$ and $q=6$):

[image]

As can be seen, I have used the [Poincaré disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) to project the hyperbolic plane to the Euclidean plane, and I have chosen the tile to be centered in the center of the disk. From this figure we can extract a set of equations:

1. $\displaystyle 2q\alpha = 2\pi$ (since the Poincaré disk model is conformal, all $q$ polygons that meet in a corner contributes with the angle $2\alpha$),
2. $\displaystyle 2p\beta = 2\pi$,
3. $\displaystyle \beta + \alpha + \beta' + \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi$ (the corners of the small right triangle has angles $\beta$, $\alpha + \beta'$ and $\pi/2$, respectively),
4. $\displaystyle R = R'\tan\gamma$ (given by the large right triangle which has corners in the circle centers and in the top intersection point between the two circles),
5. $d + R' = R\sin\gamma + R'\cos\gamma$ (the distance between the centers of the circles formed in two different ways),
6. $\displaystyle d^+ - d = R'(1 - \cos\beta')$, and
7. $\displaystyle d^+\tan\beta = R'\sin\beta'$.

From 1., 2. and 3. we get

- $\displaystyle \alpha = \frac{\pi}{q}$,
- $\displaystyle \beta = \frac{\pi}{p}$, and
- $\displaystyle \beta' = \frac{\pi}{2} - \beta + \alpha = \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}\right)\pi$.

From 4. we get

- $\displaystyle R' = \frac{R}{\tan\gamma}$,

and combining this with 5. gives $\displaystyle d + \frac{R}{\tan\gamma} = R\sin\gamma + \frac{R}{\tan\gamma}\cos\gamma$, which can be reworked into

- $\displaystyle d = \frac{1 - \cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}R$.

Now, 6. gives us $\displaystyle d^+ = \frac{1 - \cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}R + \frac{R}{\tan\gamma}(1 - \cos\beta')$, which can be worked into

- $\displaystyle d^+ = \frac{1 - \cos\gamma\cos\beta'}{\sin\gamma}R$

and 7. gives us $\displaystyle \frac{1 - \cos\gamma\cos\beta'}{\sin\gamma}R\tan\beta = \frac{R}{\tan\gamma}\sin\beta'$, which is equivalent to

- $\displaystyle \cos\gamma = \frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha} $

or

- $\displaystyle \sin\gamma = \frac{\sqrt{\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\beta}}{\cos\alpha} $

or

- $\displaystyle \tan\gamma = \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{\sin^2\beta} - 1} $

The hyperbolic distance between two adjacent corners of the tile can then be calculate as follows according to this formula I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Distance), where $P$ and $Q$ are the points in the Poincaré disc of the corners, and $A$ and $B$ are the ideal points at which the unique hyperbolic line that connects $P$ and $Q$ intersects the boundary:

$$
d(p,q)= \ln \frac{ \left| AQ \right| \, \left| PB \right| }{ \left| AP \right| \, \left| QB \right| }
$$

I have tried this formula numerically—I constructed $a$ and $b$ numerically, too, by using [gyrovector operations](https://andbloch.github.io/K-Stereographic-Model/)—but what I find more practical is to calculate the vector difference $\vec{x} = \ominus P \oplus Q$, and calculate the hyperbolic length of the resulting gyrovector as

$$
\|\vec{x}\|_{\kappa} = 2 \arctan_{\kappa}\left(\|\vec{x}\|_{\text{Euclidean}}\right)
$$

where $\vec{x}$ is the Euclidean *carrier vector* of the hyperbolic point in the Poincaré disk, $\kappa$ is the curvature of the hyperbolic space, and $\arctan_{\kappa}(x)$ is defined as

$$
\arctan_{\kappa}(x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\kappa}}\tanh(\sqrt{-\kappa} x), & \kappa < 0, \\
\displaystyle x, & \kappa = 0, \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\kappa}}\tan(\sqrt{\kappa} x), & \kappa > 0,
\end{cases}
$$

which follows by the [conformal factor](https://andbloch.github.io/K-Stereographic-Model/) of the point in the Poincaré disk (the same type of gyrovectors can also be used for spherical geometry and in Euclidean space). Using these gyrovectors I am also able to correctly position tiles in an arbitrary hyperbolic {p,q} tessellation of the hyperbolic plane in the Poincaré disk, for example this {4,6} tessellation; here is a screenshot from a small demo application I wrote in Python:

[image: {4,6} tessellation of the hyperbolic plane]

I feel like this is a good start, but it took me quite some time just to be able to calculate what I need in order to work with tiles in this simple case, and I feel like it would be nice if there was some simpler method to do this. Besides, there are many more tilings, for example an endless amount of [uniform tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane) that consist of more than one tile type and cannot be represented on the form {p,q}, and are therefore more complex. For example this snub tiling, which consists of two different types of tiles:

[image: Snub trioctagonal tiling]

So, is there some simpler method to calculate the length of a side in a tiling, and the distance from the center of a polygon to the middle of the side of the same polygon, than the method I have used here? Is there some systematic method to do this in the general case for any uniform tiling?

Comment: Can the one down voting my question, or anyone else, *please*, tell me why this isn't a good question, or how I can improve it? Did the person down voting it do so just because they couldn't answer it, or is there an actual problem with the question that I should address? It is extremely frustrating to have a question that you have asked and that is perfectly valid to you, down voted, without being given any reason why. This is perhaps the most Kafkaesque thing I have experience in real life, now when I think about it, and the biggest problem with Stack Exchange.

Comment: I did not downvote, but there are several issues with your question: (1) What information besides uniformity is given? Are you given the number of sides of each tile and the valence of one/each vertex $v$ (i.e. the number of tiles containing $v$)? (2) What do you mean by unit radius (hyperbolic plane does not have a "radius"). Do you mean the normalization that the curvature is $-1$? (3) Most importantly: What did you try to solve this problem? Did you resolve some special cases? Solved under extra assumptions? Currently, your question is a candidate for closing as 'lacking context etc."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for your reply. To answer you: (1) The number of sides of each tile and the valence are given by the vertex configuration. (2) I agree that this is unclear. Some [sources](https://andbloch.github.io/K-Stereographic-Model/) define the radius $R$ of a hyperbolic space as $\sqrt{-\kappa}$, where $\kappa$ is the curvature of the space (analogous to how the radius of a sphere with curvature $\kappa$ is $\sqrt{\kappa}$); I thought this was a convention, but maybe it's not. I will clarify this in my question.

Comment: (3) I have made an attempt for the simple case of [{p, q}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol) and I thin I have basically solved it for that case, but the calculations are quite messy and are still not for the general case. So I was wondering what the simplest way of calculating this is. I can add my calculations here if it helps.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What do you mean that my question is a candidate for closing as 'lacking context etc."? When I press close, I see that someone has given the reason "A community-specific reason / This question doesn’t meet a Mathematics Stack Exchange guideline." Do you see some more detailed reason for closing the question that I don't see?

Comment: @MoisheKohan And don't you agree that voting to close a question, or down voting it, for that matter, without also giving a reason for doing so, is very unconstructive? For me writing the question, it is _purely_ a source of frustration. I don't become any wiser to see my question having been down voted or voted for closure at all. Do you agree?

Comment: From your comments, perhaps you might be interested in reading our criteria for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and some of the subtopics under that link such as [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). You'll see under that subtopic some guidelines for *including your own work*, for example.

Comment: And another point: do not bury your attempts at providing context in the comments. Instead, hit the edit button and improve your post itself

Comment: I think it is simply false that for uniform tilings geometry is determined by combinatorics. Instead, you should restrict to (p,q) tilings. Once your question is properly revised I can write an answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I won't restrict myself to {p, q} tilings, because I want to find the solution for the general case. But I have started with a {p, q} tiling for simplicity; that case is almost done, and I will update my question with my progress. It is the general case that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: As I said, there is no solution in the general case.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What do you mean there is no solution? If I can specify a tiling unambiguously, the tiles in that tiling should have a unique side length, right?

Comment: Or do you mean that a vertex configuration doesn't necessarily uniquely specify a tiling? Because I have realized that. If so, you're right that there is no single solution in the general case if all you're given is a vertex configuration.

Comment: @LeeMosher My attempts are not buried any more.

Comment: @MoisheKohan See my updated answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - The geometry of uniform tilings is determined by combinatorics, since (in regular polygons) angles and edge lengths are monotonically related. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331199/edge-length-of-hyperbolic-tesselations .

Comment: @mr_e_man: I see, you are right! However, it does not seem to give any closed form expression except for  (p,q)-tiling cases.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hm, actually, now when I think more about it, I don't think you need to know exactly what the tiling looks like in order to determine the side length; I think only the vertex configuration should be enough (but as you say, perhaps you will not be able to obtain a closed form solution). I think it would be enough to look at just a single vertex and count the number of each tile type that it consists of. Since the corner angle of each tile can be calculated from its side length, and the sum of all angles in a vertex equals to 2π, that should give you an equation for the side length.

Comment: Haha, I realized that my comment pretty much just repeated the gist of mr_e_man's answer to the question he linked to. But whatever; I will let it stand.

Comment: You get an equation which has a unique solution. However, you will not get a solution in a closed form expression.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It doesn't look like it, no. Are you able to prove that you cannot express it in a closed form?

Comment: Proving something like this is very difficult, but given the form of the equation, I do not see any way to get a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler method for calculation in the case of $(p,q)$-tilings, i.e. tilings by regular $p$-gons where each vertex is shared by $q$ tiles. I am not going to use any models of the hyperbolic plane, only the (intrinsic) hyperbolic geometry. Let $D$ be the tile; $C$ the center of $D$. Consider a side $AB$ of $D$ and the midpoint $M$ of $AB$. We obtain a right-angled hyperbolic triangle $CAM$. Let $a$ denote the (hyperbolic) distance $d(C,M)$; let $c$ denote $d(A,M)$, the half-length of the side of $D$. Then
$$
\angle CMA= \pi/2,  \angle CAM= \pi/q, ACM= \pi/p.$$
Applying the [2nd law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines) in hyperbolic geometry we obtain:
$$
\cosh a= \frac{\cos(\pi/p)}{\sin(\pi/q)},
$$
$$
\cosh c= \frac{\cos(\pi/q)}{\sin(\pi/p)}.
$$

At this point, I am very skeptical that there is a reasonable formula for computation of side-lengths of general uniform tilings: I am not even sure how to parameterize the possible combinatorics of such tilings (so that each tiling has finitely many integer parameters) and if the combinatorics determines the geometry of individual tiles. (I thought that I can disprove the latter but I've made a mistake.)

Comment: Omg, this is so much simpler than what I just did; thank you! I didn't even know about those laws. Is there some books or other literature about the mathematics of hyperbolic spaces that you can recommend? I feel like I need to learn more mathematics like this.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: If I remember correctly, I first found these in Thurston's lecture notes where everything is derived using Lorentzian geometry, then in Marvin Greenberg's book "Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries." Check also Jim Anderson's book "Hyperbolic geometry."