# Find vertices of hyperbolic tilings in Poincare disk.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

In the hyperbolic plane, there can be tilings of regular $p$-gons with $q$ of them around a vertex. In the Poincare disk model, given that the origin is a vertex, what is the euclidean distance from the origin and a vertex connected to it?

Bonus points if you can find an efficient algorithm to find the vertices of the tiling.

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem? Do you know hyperbolic trigonometry? Do you know the relation of the Eiclidean distance from the origin to the hyperbolic  dustance? Do you assume that the center of the unit disk is also the center of a tile?

Comment: There is a dude named Zeno Rogue. You might want to talk to him.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As I said, the origin is a vertex. And yes, I do know hyperbolic trigonometry and hyperbolic distance.

Comment: OK, I missed the part that the origin is a vertex. I will then write a solution when I have more time. It is effectively just the 2nd cosine law in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Use the formula for $c$  from my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638687/how-can-we-find-sizes-in-a-uniform-tiling-of-the-hyperbolic-plane/4642524#4642524

Comment: Didn't see that question. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the distance from the center of a tile to its edge is half the distance asked for here.